# Apache Spark: impact of repartitioning, sorting and caching on a join

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I am exploring Spark's behavior when joining a table to itself. I am using Databricks.

My dummy scenario is:

1. Read an external table as dataframe A (underlying files are in delta format)
2. Define dataframe B as dataframe A with only certain columns selected
3. Join dataframes A and B on column1 and column2

(Yes, it doesn't make much sense, I'm just experimenting to understand Spark's underlying mechanics)

```
a = spark.read.table("table") \
.select("column1", "column2", "column3", "column4") \
.withColumn("columnA", lower((concat(col("column4"), lit("_"), col("column5")))))

b = a.select("column1", "column2", "columnA")

c= a.join(b, how="left", on = ["column1", "column2"])
```

My first attempt was to run the code as it is (attempt 1). I then tried to repartition and cache (attempt 2)

```
a = spark.read.table("table") \
.select("column1", "column2", "column3", "column4") \
.withColumn("columnA", lower((concat(col("column4"), lit("_"), col("column5")))))
.repartition(col("column1"), col("column2")).cache()
```

Finally, I repartitioned, sorted and cached

```
 a = spark.read.table("table") \
.select("column1", "column2", "column3", "column4") \
.withColumn("columnA", lower((concat(col("column4"), lit("_"), col("column5")))))
.repartition(col("column1"), col("column2")).sortWithinPartitions(col("column1"), col("column2")).cache()
```

The respective dags generated are as attached.

My questions are:

1. Why in attempt 1 the table appears to be cached even though caching has not been explicitly specified.
2. Why InMemoreTableScan is always followed by another node of this type.
3. Why in attempt 3 caching appears to take place on two stages?
4. Why in attempt 3 WholeStageCodegen follows one (and only one) InMemoreTableScan.

[image: attempt 1]

[image: attempt 2]

[image]

Comment: I suspect that DataFrame reader caches data automatically when the source is an external table. I have similar situation where I am reading data from a database table, while is able is being downloaded the "SQL" tab on 'Application detail UI' shows me the number of rows being downloaded but no file has been saved yet at the location specified. I guess it knows the count because it has caches the data somewhere and that is what appears on the DAG. If you read data from a text file locally then you wouldn't see the cache state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are observing in these 3 plans is a mixture of DataBricks runtime and Spark.

First of all, while running Databricks runtime 3.3+, caching is automatically enabled for all parquet files.
Corresponding config for that:
`spark.databricks.io.cache.enabled true`

For your second query, *InMemoryTableScan* is happening twice because right when join was called, spark tried to compute Dataset A and Dataset B in parallel. Assuming different executors got assigned the above tasks, both will have to scan the table from (Databricks) cache.

For the third one, *InMemoryTableScan* does not refer to caching in itself. It just means that whatever plan catalyst formed involved scanning the cached table multiple times.

PS: I can't visualize the point 4 :)